# Indesign bottom of page text alignment buggy

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm currently facing problems with text alignment in my indesign. It liberally does not line up correctly at the bottom of the text.
I've looked for several solutions about this so far I didn't get an answer.

Could someone give me a help?

[image]

Comment: are you using a the baseline grid?

Comment: i set the entire text to baseline grid to leading but dindt work. Here's the whole ad: https://prnt.sc/3qv-7xOFHZi4

Comment: well, **clearly** that subhead, and the space before it, in that column it is causing a grid jump.

Comment: I managed to find out. The alignment of the title and subtitle was causing the entire text to be misaligned. Also Leading from a title in blue down there and leading in general were also causing misalignment.

Comment: This program shouldn't work that way. It should have a way of self-alignment without having to correct everything "on the eye".

Comment: What any app *should* do and what it actual does are often entirely different. Indesign *can't* know what you intend. In some instances *not* jumping the grid may have been the wrong choice for InDesign.

Comment: If your text really is set to align to baseline grid, that misalignment shouldn't be possible. Are you sure that you did that? You also need to enter *Preferences > Grids > Baseline Grid* and set everything to fit your design. And you need to set the leading of the Paragraph Styles you use to something that makes sense. Try displaying the baseline grid using *View > Grids & Guides > Show Baseline Grid* and see if you can figure out what's happening.

Comment: Just adjust the image height till it lines up

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a subheading, with perhaps some space before it, in that longer column ....

[image]

It is *highly likely* that the subheading, it's leading or space before, is causing body copy to jump a grid slot. And therefore not align across the bottom of the page.

InDesign is software and software is dumb. All InDesign sees is that it needs X amount of vertical pace for the subheading.... then it needs to align to the baseline grid, *if possible*. If the subheading causes text to break the grid, then Indesign chooses to break the grid in favor or maintaining minimum leading (as it should).

If you need the columns to align across the bottom, that subheading needs to be adjusted to fit one or two grid spaces correctly. That will allow the body copy to align to the baseline grid properly and thus align with the other columns.